# Recover single piece/table of data from rollback on heroku postgres

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

Someone accidentally wiped a single piece of data from my heroku postgres db.

I'm looking at the rollback function that allows us to roll back the entire db to a previous point in time. 
However, some of my tables have millions of rows, whereas the table in question has a hundred or two. 
Is there a way to just provide a rollback of the individual table so I can get that piece of data (a string)?

Comment: When you "rollback" it undoes the last migration but will not repopulate data in a table.  So if you're saying that someone deleted a table in a migration, rolling back will undo the table drop but not also add the data back.

Comment: Im talking about the heroku postgres rollback function, not rake db:rollback. 
This allows me to retrieve an earlier version of the db. 
I did it by taking the whole db, just wondered if there was an easier, less resource consuming way to do it.